# Raman Scattering and the Kramers-Heisenberg Formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

Using the words of the wikipedia article [Raman Scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering):

> The Raman effect corresponds, in perturbation theory, to the absorption and subsequent emission of a photon via an intermediate vibrational state, having a virtual energy level.

From this, we can derive the [Kramers-Heisenberg Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Heisenberg_formula) for the differential cross section, which takes account of this intermediate state, but, from what I understood, excludes the absortion of more than one photon.

Well, my question is: the others processes where more than a photon is absorbed, like Hyper Raman Scattering or second Hyper Raman Scattering, are described by the Kramers-Heisenberg Formula as well?

Comment: Most likely yes, since K-H formula comes from causality principle (which is very general). Also, some papers seemed to use Kramers-Heseinberg when describing Hyper-raman scattering e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000926149385050X